# Programmatically fixed width, dynamic height UILabel?

Tags: swift, uilabel

I have a UILabel who's text changes. It has a background color that I want to always be the same width but for its height to change if needed to fit the text. Does anybody know how I might do this?

Here's what I've tried:

```
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.center = self.view.center
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0).isActive = true
    label.sizeToFit()
```

Comment: Have you written any code yet? It would be helpful to see what you have tried.

Comment: sorry, added it

Comment: Are you initialising the label with a frame?

Comment: I don't think so, in my view did load I have: `let label = UILabel()
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.center = self.view.center
        label.textAlignment = .center`

Comment: It seems to me like the left edge of the label is horizontally centered

Answer (score 1):

You should probably do some reading on [autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/) and learn how to structure your views with it, however, from what I can gather it looks like you want the label to:

- Be in the centre of the screen
- Have a fixed width
- Have a background colour
- Expand to fit its contents vertically

---

```
let label = UILabel()
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.textAlignment = .Center
label.text = "This is\nsome multiline\nlabel\nwith a background\n colour"
self.view.addSubview(label)

let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 50)
let centerX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let centerY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

self.view.addConstraints([width, centerX, centerY])
```

The above code produces a green label using autolayout, there is a [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQMCy.png).

Using `numberOfLines = 0` makes sure that the view knows the label can expand to fit it's contents.

The layout constraints should be self explanitory if you read them, we set the width of the label to `50` then we set the center X and Y contraints to be equal to the view that we added the label to.

Is this what you are after? - If not you could update your question to include a mockup image of what you are trying to make.

Answer (score -1):

Considering you are using auto layout and want to anchor your label to a view above it, you could set the *top*, *left* and *right* constraints of that label then set the `UILabel`'s `numberOfLines` to 0.

Comment: It is very possible to use bottom constraints with a multiline UILabel

Comment: Also it doesn't look like the OP is using autolayout.

Comment: @Wezly in the last edit looks like he is trying also with auto layout